# Ibase_fetch_object not returning anything

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I got a sql query that i just added new where clause and when i added that clause it stops fetching anything and if i copy the sql query and run it from program its working fine.

```
SELECT P.PROPS, P.DT_CHANGED, PI.KOLICH, S.TEGLO,S.CENA_PROD_ED1, PI.STOKA, P.DATETIME
     FROM PRODAWA P
     LEFT JOIN PRODAWA_ITEMS PI ON (P.DATETIME = PI.DATETIME)
     LEFT JOIN STOKI_DEF S ON (PI.STOKA = S.STOKA)
     WHERE P.DT_CHANGED BETWEEN '.$begindate.' AND '.$enddate.' AND P.FACTUR_BY = \'“ВЛАДИ “ ООД\' AND P.PROPS > 0  ORDER BY P.DT_CHANGED ASC
```

if i remove the clause P.FACTUR_BY It starts working.

Comment: Hi. Check your `\'“ВЛАДИ “ ООД\'` Why did you escape the quote ?

Comment: It doesnt do anything if i remove the escape still not fetching

Comment: Could be a character set problem; what is your connection character set, and are you sure that PHP is interpreting those cyrillic characters correctly?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel connection character set to NONE as it is in the Firebird database.I'm not         sure if PHP is interpreting those cyrillic characters correctly but PHP document is set to UTF-8

Comment: If you use NONE, then all bets are off; it is extremely hard to correctly reason about character sets and comparisons when NONE is used. You might be sending UTF-8, while it is stored as WIN1250, or vice versa.

Comment: but when i use software with the same query its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didn't convert UTF8 to WINDOWS-1251.Solution:
mb_convert_encoding($variable,"WINDOWS-1251") before sending the query